# Why class name of control is bad? Can not create new GDI handles?

Tags: delphi, gdi+, gdi, delphi-2007

I have a program create by Delphi language. This run on windows XP SP3.

After Open and stop program multi time (~600 to 700 times) (Only open and stop, does not do any thing). My program will be error:

- Cannot input to text box of system.
- Cannot click on some button.

When bug has occurred, the error will exist until the computer is restarted. (Restart program cannot resolve this bug)

I was check some information of system, and bellow is result:

- Total GDI handles is less than GDI handles in normal: (Use GDIView to detect that)

  - case normal: 3513 GDI handles
  - when error occur: 3410
- Class Name of control is bad: (Use spy++ detect)

  - Normal: Class name of text box is Tedit.
  - When error occur: "Toolbar_Customize" or "" or any value (This value is awlay change) ==> I think because that, i cannot input value to textbox.

Some time, i cannot start another program of windows when this bug occur.

Please help me.
P/s: any unclear please comment

Comment: Which version of Delphi? Also, when you say your program "does not do any thing" - what *exactly* does it do? Can you show the source?

Comment: I use Delphi 2007. I only start and stopped program mulit time. Do not execute another function of program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reminds me of the following issue (Resource leak caused by RM_GetObjectInstance message):
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=90511

There is a workaround in the last comment.

Comment: FYI, that issue was fixed in XE3.